# `TruncNorm: lower bound is greater than upper bound` Error in MNP package

Tags: r, bayesian, multinomial

I'm using the `MNP` package to fit Bayesian multinomial probit models to categorical data. I frequently get this error: `TruncNorm: lower bound is greater than upper bound`. How can I resolve this problem?

My sense is that this might be a convergence issue, so I've tried many different approaches on this front:

- narrower priors / changing priors
- scaling predictors, dropping highly correlated predictors
- start with one predictor then build up to more

But none of these have worked. What I have noticed is that when `n.draws` is set to a smaller number this Error comes up less frequently. Here's an example using the Iris dataset:

```
library(MNP)
data("iris")


iris$Species = as_factor(as.character(iris$Species))


res = mnp(Species ~ Sepal.Length, 
          data = iris,
          n.draws = 10000, verbose = TRUE)
summary(res)
```

The model returns the `TruncNorm` error at N = 10,000, but will finish at smaller sizes of N.